# Reporting server configuration in a sharepoint farm?

Tags: 2013, reporting-services

For configuration of  SQL SERVER Reporting server in SharePoint mode is can we install reporting services add-in for SharePoint in all servers in a SharePoint farm?

1. I did installed  reporting server in a SharePoint server, where I
   initially installed SharePoint and after installed reporting server
   and add-in for SharePoint.
2. I run  below commands in new SSRS server that joined to the farm.

   Install-SPRSService
   Install-SPRSServiceProxy
   get-spserviceinstance -all |where {$_.TypeName -like "SQL Server Reporting*"} | Start-SPServiceInstance

   TypeName                         Status      id

   --------                         ------

   SQL Server Reporting Services... Provisioned

   - but when I check system settings>Manage Services on Server there is no SQL Server Reporting Services Service
   - and also  I did not found reporting server from reporting services configuration manager in SSRS server

Comment: it should be install on all server int he farm? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Roji.Joy/configure-sql-server-reporting-services-with-sharepoint-2013/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reporting Services Manager is not used with SharePoint integrated mode on SQL Server 2012 SSRS and higher.

Make sure you're looking at the SharePoint server in Manage Services on Server that you've installed SSRS to. It will not appear on other servers where you have not installed SSRS. The SSRS Addin should be installed on all servers in the farm.

You'll need to configure SSRS through Manage Service Applications by creating a new SSRS Service Application.